# C# XAML Databinding has no effect when property is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Okay I've been wracking my brain a lot about this one, I'm missing something, I just can't figure out what.  Ultimately I'm trying to set databinding so I can update values to be shown on the fly, but for the life of me, it's not working.

The XAML is:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Height="37" Margin="85,38,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    Text="{Binding Path=TBBind}" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="121" />
```

Note that I have the `{Binding Path=TBBind}` set.

The code behind is:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace Databinding_Practice_2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TBBind = "test";
        }

        private string _tBBind;

        public string TBBind
        {
            get { return _tBBind; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _tBBind)
                {
                    _tBBind = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("TBBind");
                }
            }

        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("OnPropertyChanged triggered");
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Help me obi-w.... oh wait, help me anyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
    TBBind = "test";
}
```

The difference here sets the critical `DataContext` property. This is the cornerstone of the MVVM pattern, which you are implementing here. You should consider separating the View Model responsibility into another class, and then setting the View's `DataContext` to an instance of that class, but the approach you have taken here works for simple cases.

Comment: Thank you, i knew it was something stupid i was missing!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are trying to use the MVVM pattern (which stands for Model-View-ViewModel):

Your MainWindow is the View.

You should create another class to be the View Model, like this:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        TBBind = "test";
    }

    private string _tBBind;

    public string TBBind
    {
        get { return _tBBind; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _tBBind)
            {
                _tBBind = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TBBind");
            }
        }

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("OnPropertyChanged triggered");
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

Your MainWindow code behind will become like this after removing all ViewModel related stuff to the MainWindowViewModel class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}
```

Now, you should link the View with the ViewModel, there are many ways to do this. Here is one of them:

In the XAML of MainWindow, have the following inside the `Window` element:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <wpfApplication5:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37" Margin="85,38,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding TBBind}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="121" />
</Grid>
```

Please note that `WpfApplication5` is the name of the namespace in my WPF project. This will probably be different in your case.

Comment: Thankyou, i ended up marking codekaizen's answer as correct as its the simpliest incase anyone has the same problem(although yours explained what was going on a lot better).  Id upvote your answer but the restriction on 15 reputation :s

Comment: Thanks codekaizen! When i have enough rep ill come back and upvote it too haha.