# C# wpf updating databound value from another script

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Okay for reference i previously asked:
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32727918/c-sharp-xaml-databinding-has-no-effect-when-property-is-changed)

Now i have databound the text box so that it will update on the MainWindow without an issue

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    updateTickerText("testing from button");
}
```

now that works perfectly fine, to call the following:

```
public void updateTickerText(string value)
{
    TickerText = value;
}
```

BUT, if i try and call updateTickerText from another page, such as this:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
    //mw.TickerText = "Testing";
    mw.updateTickerText("Testing");
}
```

It says its firing the event(i have a messagebox set on trigger for value change), but its not updating the databound textblock.

Extra:
My TextBlock

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TickerTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="0,347,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path = TickerText, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="692"  />
```

So to recap: I can update the TextBlock's bind TickerText without a problem when calling it from the MainWindow, but when i call the same function from another page its not updating.

Also im using an imbeded Frame to load pages, and the TickerTextBlock is on the main form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating a new object here:

```
MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
//mw.TickerText = "Testing";
mw.updateTickerText("Testing");
```

You have guaranteed that your function call will not affect anything on screen. The new object is not visible on-screen, and has *nothing* in common with the actual visible instance of `MainWindow` other than the class.

So, you need to pass in the existing instance of your data context and invoke `UpdateTickerText` (capitalization on public methods!) on *that*. You can do this by passing it on the constructor, using a service locator, or several other methods.

As an aside, you shouldn't be using the view class as your view model. Having separated view and view model classes makes stuff like this a lot cleaner.

Comment: Okay thanks, ill look into that and get back to you.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, work got busy.  Thank you, i was able to figure it out eventually.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you a referencing the correct MainWindow instance?
Looks to me you are creating a new one

```
MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
```